# Creating a resume template - need help with the education part

Tags: resume

I am working on creating a resume template for people like me aka complete newbies to Latex, exploring the lay of the land.
I have been working on modularizing what I have and while working on the education part, I started with creating a table of two columns, the contents of which are flushed left, and ragged right (to push the dates to the extreme right).
Here's the code for my education section:

```
\vspace{-4mm}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.75\textwidth}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.25\textwidth}}
     \textbf{Ms. in Computer Science}, Northeastern University, MA & Sept. 2021 - May 2023 \\
     \textbf{B.E in Computer Engineering}, Pune University, IN & Aug. 2016 - May 2020
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\vspace{-7mm}
```

And I am trying to create a style file .sty for storing the commands, importing appropriate libraries.
Please help me create three new commands from the above code:

1. ResumeEducationListStart - to include

```
\vspace{-4mm}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{0.75\textwidth}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.25\textwidth}}
```

2. ResumeEducationItem - to include

```
\textbf{Ms. in Computer Science}, Northeastern University, MA & Sept. 2021 - May 2023 \\
```

and finally 3. ResumeEducationListEnd - to include

```
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\vspace{-7mm}
```

For some reason, I can not simply break the code into three: The error hints at the 'table' being started and ending at \end{document}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Comment: There are plenty of bad templates available on the web.  Do we really need another?

Comment: True, I was trying to create one that is readable and well documented - for people like me.

Comment: Hello @JamesT I will definitely do that, thank you